# I have deleted systemd

Tags: debian, systemd

I am a Debian user.

I deleted systemd without installing anything else.

I ran `sudo apt remove systemd`.
After that, I ran    `sudo apt autoremove systemd`.

After that, my laptop can’t connect to the internet, and it doesn’t get me to use the GUI; I'm stuck in the command line interface  (which I can run commands in after login). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you delete the executable or the package? What command did you run to do this deletion? Also can you describe the CLI? Is there a login prompt or not?

Comment: I run sudo apt remove systemd

Comment: I think so it has replaced to system v     . Yes there is long in prompt

Comment: @Hussain Why did you delete it?

Comment: Aha the reason behind that is a little bit laughable but i hear that a lot of people hate that system so I deleted it I know that it was a quick discussion but that what happened 

Comment: I believe it takes a bit more to create a [Devuan Linux](https://www.devuan.org) system.  Not having tried to remove systemd from an existing Debian installation, I would only suggest that you instead install Devuan and restore your important data from your external backups, or that you try to log in as root (possibly using rescue mode, possibly via a LiveCD Debian system), backup your data, and _then_ install Devuan (assuming that is the system you actually want to run).

Comment: Yes your right devuan would be a better option for me

Comment: But see [A.B's detailed answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/772961/116858) below (or any other that pops up to help you with what you actually asked about in the text of your question).

Comment: Are you in the so-called "emergency shell"? Linux will try to boot up by running an init system (boot-up system) like systemd or something else; if none is found, it will directly run a shell so that at least you can have a fighting chance to fix it. It should be possible to get the system connected to the internet and reinstall systemd; you'll just have to do it yourself instead of relying on the system that normally connects you automatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll assume all commands below are run as root user. Either login directly as root, or if you can't, log instead as the user allowed to use `sudo` and use `sudo -i`: there should be a root prompt with a `#` at its end.

You should backup the contents of `/var/log/apt` with

```
cp -a /var/log/apt /root/log-apt-backup
```

so you can later find what other deleted package you might have to install back.

As support for system V is slowly degrading, I can assume that some GUI parts rely on systemd features and thus fail to start.

You should reinstall `systemd`, but this might not be enough: to trigger additional needed dependencies, instead you should remove what provides System V's `/sbin/init`: `sysvinit-core`. The same way removing `systemd` triggered installation of replacement system V packages, removing this one will trigger replacement in the systemd ecosystem.

Tested this on an empty LXC container:

```
root@bookworm-test:~# apt remove systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  initscripts insserv orphan-sysvinit-scripts sensible-utils startpar sysv-rc
  sysvinit-core ucf
Suggested packages:
  bootchart2 bootlogd
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  dbus-user-session libnss-systemd libpam-systemd systemd systemd-resolved
  systemd-sysv
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  initscripts insserv orphan-sysvinit-scripts sensible-utils startpar sysv-rc
  sysvinit-core ucf
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and later after reboot fixes etc (don't run this, won't be enough):

```
# apt install systemd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  systemd-timesyncd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot
  systemd-resolved libqrencode4 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0
  polkitd | policykit-1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  systemd systemd-timesyncd
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

won't do enough to be useful (it would stay with sys V init).

Instead:

```
root@bookworm-test:~# apt remove sysvinit-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  initscripts insserv startpar sysv-rc
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session libnss-systemd libpam-systemd systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd
Suggested packages:
  systemd-container systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot
  systemd-resolved libqrencode4 libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0
  polkitd | policykit-1
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sysvinit-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session libnss-systemd libpam-systemd systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

appears more useful. At least one suggested package should be installed back: `polkitd` (by appending a `+` at the end, this can be done within a `remove` operation). So in the end run:

```
apt remove sysvinit-core polkitd+
```

This requires network. It appears OP (and actually my LXC test) doesn't have network anymore by default. This should be fixable easily with a wired Ethernet interface named `eth0` (actual name can be retrieved from `ip -br link`'s results, replace `eth0` below with it if needed):

```
dhclient -v eth0
```

then try again the previous `apt` command.

on a minimal system something like this would be displayed:

```
# apt remove sysvinit-core polkitd+
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  initscripts insserv startpar sysv-rc
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session libduktape207 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libicu72
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libxml2 sgml-base shared-mime-info systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  xdg-user-dirs xml-core
Suggested packages:
  low-memory-monitor polkitd-pkla sgml-base-doc systemd-container
  systemd-homed systemd-userdbd systemd-boot systemd-resolved libqrencode4
  libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 libtss2-mu0 libtss2-rc0 debhelper
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sysvinit-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus-user-session libduktape207 libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-data libicu72
  libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0
  libxml2 polkitd sgml-base shared-mime-info systemd systemd-sysv
  systemd-timesyncd xdg-user-dirs xml-core
0 upgraded, 18 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and reboot, to switch back to systemd. This might or might not restore the GUI, but this should have switched back to `systemd`. To verify, one can run (as root):

```
ldd /proc/1/exe | grep systemd
```

which should have non-empty output.

Once above is done, examine the log backup in `/root/log-apt-backup/history.log` and search for a line looking like the commands you did: `Commandline: apt remove systemd` and `Commandline: apt autoremove systemd`. Check all removed packages shown below their respective `Remove:` entry, and add back what might still be missing.

Comment: Hence i dont have internet connection so the additional package in the remove of sysv init cant be installed

Comment: after removing systemv init and install systemd and reboot   I run ps-p 1 it still show init        . Please write the command line that I should see from its out put what has been missed

Comment: Either init didn't start network services or removing systemd removed network management tooks like network-manager.  Might be able to manually bring up the interface by running `dhclient` but if that doesn't work, it's gonna be complicated.

Comment: Aha such a big trouble 

Comment: @Hussain So to get network. If using Ethernet (wired): get the interface name using `ip -br link`. Then run `dhclient -v eth0` (replace eth0 with the actual interface name from the previous command). If using Wifi, plan B: have a live image available on USB stick or on CD. Which is it for you?

Comment: Btw, for anything more difficult (eg: Wifi and can't get network and don't want to figure out if enough commands are available to start it), the plan B is described there (and can then be followed the apt commands in my answer): https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive

Comment: @Hussain as written in the answer: look for the lines having `Remove:` in them. They'll show what was removed because of the apt commands. Find the ones below the two `Commandline:` having your two apt remove systemd and similar commands. It shows everything (which might be a lot) that was removed because of this. This gives a list of packages to potentially put back. Where are you having a problem in this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152204/discussion-between-hussain-and-a-b).

Comment: I'm stuck on sysvinit due to *one* bug left in systemd. There's a compatibility package; most things work once it's installed. I haven't encountered something that definitely doesn't work since snap.